# In finding the MLE or using an approach like the EM algorithm, how can you find the global maximum if there are multiple local maxima?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

In the EM algorithm, one of its drawbacks is that it cannot always find the global maximum, and hence something like deterministic annealing is applied. However, what if we have multiple maxima that are close to each other? (think of it as multiple mountains with the same elevation) Is there some way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

If the elevation is exactly the same, then you have a problem of **identifiability** of your model. Indeed every maximum provides the same fit to your data.

However, if you allow yourself to change the model, you can decide to choose:

- The best fit with the smallest number of non-zero components
- The best fit with the smallest $l^p$-norm (the previous example is actually $p=0$).